# Children's book about a magican's apprentice

Tags: story-identification, books

The boy who helps solve a prince's murder or something along those lines. The boy had tarot cards in the first chapter, draws the Death card, and says how it's about new beginnings? I'm sorry, that's all I remember from back when I was ten.

Comment: You say you read this when you were ten, but how long ago was that? Can you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### *[Midnight Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/122913.Midnight_Magic)*, by Avi

[image: Cover of "Midnight Magic" by Avi. The cover is shaded blue, black, and white. A silhouette of a boy sneaks up a spiral staircase, as lightning crackles across the night sky outside.]

The book opens with Fabrizio, the Magician's servant / apprentice, drawing the "Death" tarot card:

> In 1491, in the Kingdom of Pergamontio, there lived a twelve-year-old boy by the name of Fabrizio. He was the sole servant of Mangus the Magician.
> [...]
> Eyes shut, praying to see *Riches*, Fabrizio turned over the ninth and final card. When he opened his eyes and saw that the card was
> DEATH
> he gasped.
> <sub>*Midnight Magic*, chapter 1</sub>

The Magician and Fabrizio are summoned to the castle to deal with a troublesome ghost, who is then revealed to apparently be the ghost of the Prince:

> When Princess Teresina hesitated, Fabrizio leaned forward to hear her answer.
> Finally, the girl said, "I know it."
> Mangus: "Do you think you know whose ghost this is?"
> Princess Teresina: "My brother's."
> "Brother!" Scarazoni cried with such vehemence, Fabrizio started. "You never said so before, Princess."
> <sub>*Midnight Magic*, chapter 12</sub>

---

Identified by recognizing the description in the question.